# wal-e/wal-g any benefit for simple backup and restore via S3

Tags: rds, wal, wal-e

I'm using AWS RDS and have a need to replicate "database_a" in an RDS instance to "database_a" in a different RDS instance.  The replication only needs to be once every 24 hours.

I'm currently solving this with pg_dump and pg_restore but am wondering if there is a better (ie faster/more efficient) way I can go about things.

Using wal-e/g and RDS, is it at all possible for my use case to simply push the latest changes from the last say 24 hours?  The 2 RDS cannot speak to each other so all connection would be by S3.  I'm not clear what the docs mean by '[When uploading backups to S3, the user should pass in the path containing the backup started by Postgres](https://github.com/wal-g/wal-g):' - does this mean i can create a pg backup to my EC2 and then point wal-g at this backup?

Finally, is it at all possible to just use wal-e/g for complete backups (ie non incremental) just as i am doing now with pg_dump/pg_restore and in doing so would I see a speed improvement by switching?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

In a word, yes.

- On a system using dump/restore, you're consuming a lot more CPU and network resources (therefore costs) which you could reduce notably by using the WALs for incremental backups, and only doing an image perhaps once a week.  This is especially true if your database is mostly data that doesn't change.  It might be incorrect if your database is not growing but is made of records that are updated many times per 24 hours (e.g. stock prices).
- Once you are publishing WALs to S3 frequently, then you'll have a far more up to date backup than nightly backups.
- When publishing WALs you can recover to any point in time
- WAL-E and WAL-G both have built in encryption
- There is also differential backup support, but not something I've played with